# Right algorithm for dependent inputs type range

Tags: javascript, range, percentage

How to calculate percentage of sliders (i.e. `<input type="range">`), that their sum is 100%;

In this example, when I set the second slider value to 95%, other sliders value are set to 3%. How to fix it?

```
// Calculate fraction
if (sum <= 0) {
  fraction = 1 / (depends.length - 1)
} else {
  fraction = val / sum;
}

// The last element will correct rounding errors
if (i >= depends.length - 1) {
  val = max - partial;
} else {
  val = Math.round(delta * fraction);
  partial += val;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vLaj37hf/

Comment: Setting "step" for all the `input` component to "2", instead of "5"

Comment: I need all x5% values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking, if the total of all the values of `<input type="range">` is greater than the max value which is `100`. If true you can find the difference and subtract it from the last value. This might not be the best solution. Please see below.

```js
var depends = document.querySelectorAll('.depend');

[].forEach.call(depends, function(depend) {
  depend.onchange = function() {
    s(this, this.value);
    c(this);
  }
});

function c(current) {
  var input = current.value;
  var max = 100;
  var delta = max - parseInt(input);
  var sum = 0;
  var partial = 0;
  var siblings = [];

  // Sum of all siblings
  [].forEach.call(depends, function(depend) {
    if (current != depend) {
      siblings.push(depend); // Register as sibling
      sum += +depend.value;
    }
  });

  // Update all the siblings
  siblings.forEach(function(subling, i) {

    var val = +subling.value;
    var fraction = 0;

    // Calculate fraction
    if (sum <= 0) {
      fraction = 1 / (depends.length - 1)
    } else {
      fraction = val / sum;
    }

    // The last element will correct rounding errors
    if (i >= depends.length - 1) {
      val = max - partial;
    } else {
      val = Math.round(delta * fraction);
      partial += val;
    }

    // Check if total of all range is greater than max value
    var total = partial + parseInt(input);
    if (total > max) {
      var diff = total - max; // Calculate the difference
      val = val - diff; // Update the value
      partial = partial - diff;
    }

    s(subling, val);
  });
}

function s(el, value) {
  var label = document.getElementById(el.id + '_value')
  label.innerHTML = value;
  el.value = value;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="depend" min="0" max="100" value="70" step="5" id="one">
<label id="one_value">70</label>%
<br>
<input type="range" class="depend" min="0" max="100" value="30" step="5" id="two">
<label id="two_value">30</label>%
<br>
<input type="range" class="depend" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="5" id="three">
<label id="three_value">0</label>%
<br>
```

Comment: Thank's, that's right, but not 5% step. My decision is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vLaj37hf/1/), but only for 3 inputs.